# How to pass foreign key of table into table value parameter

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables `Employee` and `Department`. I created a stored procedure to add multiple employees to a department. For that, I created a table-valued employee type and got department id and other details from the stored procedure parameters.

The problem is `departmentId` is a foreign key in the `Employee` table and I want to put that foreign key on all rows of the table-valued parameter.

This is how the schema looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
    [Id] int PRIMARY KEY,
    [DepartmentId] FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Department(Id)
    [FName] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    [LName] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    [Age] TINYINT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Department
(
    [Id] int PRIMARY KEY,
    [Name] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    [Description] VARCHAR(200)
);

CREATE TYPE EmployeeType 
   AS TABLE
      (
        [Id] int,
        [FName] VARCHAR(100),
        [LName] VARCHAR(100),
        [Age] TINYINT
      );
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE bulkEmployeeInsertion
    @DepartmentId INT,
    @Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    @Description VARCHAR(200),
    @Employees EmployeeType READONLY
AS         
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Department 
    VALUES (@DepartmentId, @Name, @Description)

    INSERT INTO Employee
        SELECT * 
        FROM @EmployeeType
END
```

How to store `departmentId` into the `employee` table?

Comment: You could start by fixing the syntax error in employee, also what function does employeetype serve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this - **explicitly specify** the columns of the `Department` and  `Employee` tables you're inserting into (a generally accepted Best Practice - to use always, anyway), and add the `@DepartmentID` parameter into the list of values:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE bulkEmployeeInsertion
    @DepartmentId INT,
    @Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    @Description VARCHAR(200),
    @Employees EmployeeType READONLY
AS         
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Department (Id, Name, Description)
    VALUES (@DepartmentId, @Name, @Description)

    INSERT INTO Employee (Id, DepartmentId, FName, LName, Age)
        SELECT 
            Id, @DepartmentId, FName, LName, Age
        FROM  
            @EmployeeType    
END
```

So now you're basically inserting the four values from your table-valued parameter, plus you're adding the one value for `@DepartmentId` to each row you're inserting.